# c# Regex more than one word

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text for example , Nim-Qloth, Iceberg, Szatan Krul, Consequence, Arithael,    and I use regex to find text between `, ,` I have that code

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(miejscepliku))
{
    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    String odbiorca = Regex.Match(line, @"\, ([^,]*)\,").Groups[1].Value;
    textBox3.Text = odbiorca;
}
```

My code find one word and word is showing in `textbox3` word is `"Nim-Qloth"` but i want click second time and find next word ex. `"Iceberg"`. How do that?

Comment: You don't need regex for this task. `String.Split` will do the job.

Comment: Are you looking for `line.Split(',')[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Split` is sufficient and more efficient:

```
String[] odbiorca = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You can access an array by index(zero based). You just need to store the current index so that you can show the next on each button-click.

```
private int currentIndex = -1; // a field in your class

...

if(++currentIndex == odbiorca.Length) currentIndex = 0;
string currentWord = odbiorca[currentIndex];
```